# VM Backups - Externalizing extra large VMware backups

Tags: backup, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

I have a couple of VMware ESXi hosts with a couple of VMs on each hosts. The total amount of size of all these VMs are in the order of the TBs.

I want to make backups of these VMs. But here is not the problem. I already make backups using **ghettoVCB** on a network share. But in the event of a disaster in the office, like a fire, I would lose all these backups kept in the office.

We cannot transfer these backups on another location over the internet because its too large.

What are traditional best practices in externalizing extra large backups like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the (probably zipped) vcb images to cheap disks weekly or monthly or as suits taste; and rotate the disks through a locally rented bank safe.

Also, there are safes on the market that can withstand a direct building fire with media in them intact for a well specified amount of time.

Comment: The fire proof safe is a great idea, i didnt thought about this, thanks!

Comment: @JonathanRioux, a fireproof safe is a great idea, unless the office is inaccessible due to a fire... or other event. Never keep the data you need to restore your environment in a DR scenario in the same location as the environment you're protecting in the first place. If the facilities burn down it does you little good to have the data in a fireproof safe if you can't get to it.

Answer (score 1):

You either have a high-bandwidth dedicated connection to another location (usually via leased fiber) so you can sync backups there, or you have physical drives or tapes that are cycled out to an offsite location in rotation for safekeeping.

Keep in mind when transporting physical media (drives/tapes/etc.) you would probably want to encrypt them.